# She doesn't like you go in her room

Tags: grammar

He went in his sister room.

> "Don't go inside. She doesn't like you go in her room."
>
> "Don't go inside. She doesn't like you to go in her room."

Go or to go？Which one is the correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct one is:

> "Don't go inside. She doesn't like you **to go** in her room."

You can only have one active verb in a sentence (or clause). Here that verb is **like**, as the primary verb with the auxiliary **do**. Whatever follows is the object of her dislike.

> She doesn't like < something >.

Then, **go** is a secondary verb and can be in the infinitive form **to go** or the gerund form **going**.

So the construction can be either:

> She doesn't like you **to go** in her room. (Infinitive)

or

> She doesn't like you **going** in her room. (Gerund)

It cannot be

> She doesn't like you **go** in her room."

because **go** is not the active verb here.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the wrong word choice, in my opinion. When you use the verb *like* like that, a common word to use is *when*:

> She doesn't like it **when** random people enter her room.

In your case, I would suggest that you switch to the verb *want* instead:

> Don't go inside. She doesn't **want** you to enter her room.

But on the technical side of things, you do need to use a *to* in front of the second verb:

> I would **like** you **to** be my friend.

Comment: In the first case, the more simple correction would be "She doesn't like you going in her room."

Thinking about it, some verbs require a present-continuous tense (she hates you going, she sees you going) and others infinitive (she wants you to go, she allows you to go) and I'm racking my brain trying to figure out the underlying reason for this and I think it's a simple irregularity of the verbs. I'm researching it, but if anyone else wants to chime in...

Comment: You know, language can sometimes be such a delicate thing that so much just depends on context. If there's not enough of it, different people will think slightly different things.

Comment: I don't understand. What are you saying that in respects to?

Comment: I'm talking about the correction that you offered. My examples just happened to be different from that of yours. That's all.